# Why would a PHP function call work on my local host but not on the server?

Tags: php

The "save" function call works on my local host but not on the server. Strangely the call to the same "save" function works in other PHP routines in the same project on the server.

Code from the calling routine

```
$house= House::find_by_id($idhouse);    // This works
$house->idmobile=$_POST['idmobile'];    // and this
$house->status='L';                     // and this
if ($house->save()) {                    // this gives a fatal error
```

Relevant Function code

```
<?php
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'db.php');

class House extends DatabaseObject {
    protected static $table_name="house";
    protected static $db_flds = array('id', 'iduser', 'mobile', 'status', 'deleted');

    public $id;
    public $iduser;
    public $mobile;
    public $status;
    public $deleted;

    public static function find_by_id($id = 0) {
        $result = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name . " WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result) ? array_shift($result) : false;
    }

    public function save() {
        return isset($this->id) ? $this->update() : $this->create();
    }
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in
>   /house/XXXXXX/public_html/xml_post.php on line 12

I have tried calling "create" direct but fails with the same error type.

Comment: clearly `find_by_id()` is not returning an object of that type. does `find_by_sql()` return an array of `House` objects?

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem. Find_by_id($id) works and find_by_sql() does return an array of objects on localhost. save()  works on localhost but not on the server.

Comment: Is your directory structure the same on the server as it is on your local host or is one of the files in a different place? Specifically the file containing the house class or db.php?

Comment: The structure is identical. They all sit in their own directories. Yesterday the code worked and I did change some code but nothing that affects the database.